# Create Chatbot and it features using smooch.io API

Tags: bots, chat, chatbot, smooch

I'd like to ask anyone who has tried to create a chatbot, does [smooch.io](https://smooch.io/) support creating a chatbot using their API? If not, can someone give advice on which platform help create a chatbot using their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into https://dev.botframework.com/
It's very easy to use for creating and integrating with many chat providers.

Comment: Thanks  , I'll look into it